# combine two .htaccess rewrite files

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two different .htaccess files each doing different things and when i combine them they won't work together.

the first one allows me to enter www.mydoman.com/test and have it mean www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=test

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$  index.php?subclass=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^.* index.php [NC,L]
```

The second file cuts off the extension from .html and .php files so can use www.mydomain.com/about insted of www.mydoman.com/about.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /cl_clone

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Is there a way to allow both of these to work together in one .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You have a redirect rule at the top, and then 2 sets of rules to add either the php or html extensions to the end of the request, if such a file exists. Then your other rule does routing for index.php.

Some things you'll need to work out. You have the rewrite base `/cl_clone` which doesn't seem like it's going to work at all, in either of the cases, because your URLs don't have `cl_clone` in the request (e.g. they are simply `www.mydomain.com/about`, no cl_clone).

So you probably want to remove that.

Otherwise, you can simply add the `index.php` routing rules at the very bottom of the other rules that you have. You may need to add additional tweaking, perhaps:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$  index.php?subclass=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule    ^.* index.php [NC,L]
```

Or changing your `RewriteBase /cl_clone` to `RewriteBase /`